# What did Troi mean by this?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-insurrection

In *Star Trek: Insurrection* movie, there was this funny conversation:

> **Deanna Troi:** Have you noticed how your boobs have started to firm up?
>   **Beverly Crusher:** Not that we care about such things in this day and age.
>   **Deanna Troi:** Uh-huh.
>   [notices Data]
>   **Beverly Crusher:** Thank you, Data.
>   [Data walks up to Worf]
>   **Worf:** I have an odd craving for the blood of a live Kolar beast. This environment must be affecting me again.
>   **Data:** And have you noticed how your boobs have started to firm up? Not that we care about--

I am interested in the first sentence of the above conversation. I guessed that it has something to do with being young again, but what exactly was Troi talking about? Which biological phenomenon?

Comment: Actually, in a deleted scene, Worf tries to slug Data for asking such a nosy question. It doesn't end well for him.

Comment: Data repeating the question I always found somewhat odd, hilarious but odd

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptosis_(breasts)) (warning, article contains images of breasts)

> **Ptosis:**
> *Female breast ptosis or 'sagging' is a natural consequence of aging ... A woman's breasts change in size, volume, and position on her chest throughout her life. In young women with large breasts, sagging may occur early in life due to the effects of gravity. It may be primarily caused by the volume and weight of the breasts which are disproportionate to her body size.*

The metaphasic particle thingies are causing the women's bodies to de-age slightly. This has the effect of causing *a more youthful physique and attitude* to emerge. Note that this is also happening in the men with Worf suffering from pimples, Riker feeling the urge to shave his beard and Picard becoming romantically involved with a Baku lady.

> *The collar had been loose, because the skin of his neck-which a day or
> two ago had been wrinkled, sagging, causing Beverly to complain-was
> taut, firm.*
>
> *Young.*
>
> *Young, as though during his day with the Baku, he had aged in reverse
> five, ten years. Marveling, he ran a finger beneath his chin, and saw
> the impossible. As the mambo swelled in the background, Picard
> searched for the familiar wrinkles around his eyes, upon his brow….*
>
> *The newer ones, gone. The older, distinctly fainter*
>
> <sub><sup>[Insurrection: Official Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: I never fully understood how the de-ageing worked on the Enterprise crew so fast when it was a plot point that some of the Sona would die before the planet had a chance to de-age them

Comment: @revenant If ageing processes are faster than de-ageing processes, one would die. It's possible Sona's ageing processes had been accelerated to that point. Also, Enterprise crew were healthy and relatively young.